# Estimate a probability from elements of a list in R

Tags: r, probability

I have a list of 100,000 simulated numbers of T in R  (min: 1.5, max 88.8) and I want to calculate the probability of T being between 10 and 50.

I sumulated 100,000 numbers of T,  where T   is  `t(y) %*% M %*% y` where `M` is a 8x8 matrix of constant values and y is a 8x1 matrix. The element in the `i`-th row if y, is equal to:  `a_i + b_i`      where a is a vector of constants   and b is a vector whose elements follow a `normal  (0,sd=2)`  distribution   (each element is a different simulated number of `N(0,2)`  )

Comment: From what probability distribution were they sampled?

Comment: I sumulated 100,000 numbers of T,  where T   is  t(y)%*%M%*%y where M is a 8x8 matrix of constant values and y is a 8x1 matrix. The element in the i-th row if y, is equal to:  a_i + b_i      where a is a vector of constants   and b is a vector whose elements follow a normal   (0,sd=2)  distribution   (each element a different simulated number of N(0,2)  )

Comment: Do you have a list or a vector?  Providing a small reproducible data set always helps.

Comment: Here is a link on how to make reproducible data in R http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Is it in a vector or a list? If it's a vector, the following should work. If it's in a list, you may use unlist() to convert it to a vector.

```
mylist <- runif(100000,1.5,88.8) #this is just to generate a random number vector 
length(which(mylist>=10 & mylist<=50))/length(mylist)
```

Comment: My favorite succinct coding for the scenario in @Sean's answer is `mean(mylist>=10 & mylist<=50)`

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(42)
myrandoms <- rnorm(100000, mean=5, sd=2)
mydistr <- ecdf(myrandoms)

#probability of beeing between 1 and 3:
diff(mydistr(c(1, 3)))
#[1] 0.13781

#compare with normal distribution
diff(pnorm(c(1, 3), mean=5, sd=2))
#[1] 0.1359051
```

If you really have a list, use `myrandoms <- do.call(c, mylist)` to make it a vector.

Comment: If you plan on calculating a lot of empirical probabilities this would be a good way to go - if you only plan on calculating one then aosmith's comment in Sean's answer is probably better.

Comment: How can we comment on the comparison between the probability which was calculated from the simulated numbers and the probability of the original distribution?

Comment: @user3143784 I don't really understand your comment. The theoretical and simulated results match quite nicely and if you increase the sample size they match even better.