# How to compute the probability given a data set in R?

Tags: r, probability, probability-density

I have a vector with values which distribution is unknown and i want to create another vector with the probabilities of the values i have. 
eg.

I have

```
v <- c(e1, e2, ... , ei)
```

and i want to create

```
p <- c(P(e1), P(e2), ... , P(ei))
```

How can i do this in R?

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843627/estimate-a-probability-from-elements-of-a-list-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to create a vector the same length as the vector of values, you could do something like:

```r
p <- sapply(v, function(x) length(which(x == v))/length(v))
```

**Example** using letters as values

```r
set.seed(123)
v = sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace = TRUE)

p <- sapply(v, function(x) length(which(x == v))/length(v))
p
#>   b   d   b   d   d   a   c   d   c   b 
#> 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.2 0.3
```